# How to find distance between 2 lat lng present in 2 variable which array of 2 variable

Tags: scala

I am trying to calculate distance between 2 lat lng from 2 variable and check if they are below cutoff then 0 value else 1

```
val loc1 = Array("12.764,76.833","12.763,76.839","12.762,76.832")
val loc2 = Array("12.764,76.836")

val cut_off = Array(10)

val R = 6372.8  //Earth radius in km

def getHaversineDistance(p1Lat: Double, p1Long: Double, p2Lat: Double, p2Long: Double): Double = {
    val dLat=(p2Lat - p1Lat).toRadians
    val dLon=(p2Long - p1Long).toRadians
    val a = pow(sin(dLat/2),2) + pow(sin(dLon/2),2) * cos(p1Lat.toRadians) * cos(p2Lat.toRadians)
    R * 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
}
```

Here loc1 contains different place lat and lng .loc2 is the lat lng which should be compared against all the lat and lng of loc1 and compare with the cutoff value.

Comment: Seems straightforward enough (parse String into pair of Double, `filter` those against the result of `getHaversineDistance`), which part do you have trouble with? What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am stuck in parsing the lat lng into the function.How to parse does it require loop.

Comment: You could parse the Strings like this: `loc1.map{x => val Array(lat, lng) = x.split(",").map(_.toDouble); (lat, lng)}`. Gives you an `Array[(Double, Double)]`

Comment: do you have to parse? why not just make  them tuples???? ```val loc1 = Array((12.764,76.833), (12.763,76.839), (12.762,76.832))```

Comment: How can we calculate the distance using HaversineDistance if we do not parse .Is there any way we can do that

Comment: Once you have the doubles (parsed from strings, or directly as literals in your program as @GMc suggests), you can call the `HaversineDistance` function.

Comment: First of all, you can not use `Double`, `Float` for Lat, Lng. You should use `BigDecimal` because you do not want to change your `Lat, Lng` because of precision snaps.

Comment: @Thilo I am not sure if its required loop to calculate the distance .After parsing how can we call haversine function using map or use loop to traverse over both location variable.I am new to scala .

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Really? How long (in metres) is the imprecision on Double?

Comment: You can get the distance from a list of locations to `loc2` using `locations.map { loc => getHaversineDistance(loc._1, loc._2, loc2._1, loc2._2)`

Comment: @Thilo He has `Strings` not `Tuples`. It depends on the application... we never know... he may as well be working on building the Xenomorph targeting engine for an ultra high precision laser powered by a dyson sphere... and I for certain do not want that laser to miss.

Comment: @Thilo Problem with precision-loss is that they keep on adding up. https://www.gao.gov/products/IMTEC-92-26

Comment: @AshwinPadhy you can use map, sure. Or loop. Whatever you prefer. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh by that logic (we don't know what precision he needs), your advice is good for every single case using `Double` everywhere :)

Comment: Given that the Earth is not a perfect sphere (it is "fatter" than it is "taller" by about 20km) any error 15 decimal places (a double value) is probably enough precision to be getting on with - especially given there is a 0.5% error in the haversine formula in the first place (not because of doubles, because the earth is not a perfect sphere). But, @Sarvesh_Kumar_Singh if you prefer to use BigDecimal, by all means do so. BTW, if you are building a "Xenomorph targetting engine for a dyson sphere requiring ultra high precision", use something like the vincenty's formula not haversine.

Answer (score 0):

This code works but you should add some error checking on parser

```
import Math._

val loc1 = Array("12.764,76.833", "12.763,76.839", "12.762,76.832")
val loc2 = Array("12.764,76.836")

val cut_off = Array(10)

val R = 6372.8 //Earth radius in km

def getHaversineDistance(p1Lat: Double, p1Long: Double,p2Lat: Double, p2Long: Double): Double = {
  val dLat = (p2Lat - p1Lat).toRadians
  val dLon = (p2Long - p1Long).toRadians
  val a = pow(sin(dLat / 2), 2) + pow(sin(dLon / 2), 2) * cos(p1Lat.toRadians) * cos(
  p2Lat.toRadians)
  R * 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
}

def toList(arr: Array[String]): Seq[(Double, Double)] =
  arr.map(x => (x.split(",")(0).toDouble, x.split(",")(1).toDouble)).toList

val res = for {
  l1 <- toList(loc1)
  l2 <- toList(loc2)
} yield getHaversineDistance(l1._1, l1._2, l2._1, l2._2)

 println(res) // List(0.32543327331680283, 0.34391646279701354, 0.48761200638246516)
```